# copy the value with last non zero value sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data as below, data is order by date.

I need to copy the last non zero value when there is zero. For example 15th August the count is Zero so the count should show 20 as the last count is 20 (on 15th August), same should happen for 16th - 19 August. Now for 21st - 22nd the count should be 14. If no previous value is available let it be zero in case of 14th Aug.

I have also added the result at last.

```
Date    Count
14-Aug-15   0
15-Aug-15   20
16-Aug-15   0
17-Aug-15   0
18-Aug-15   0
19-Aug-15   0
20-Aug-15   14
21-Aug-15   0
22-Aug-15   0
23-Aug-15   10
24-Aug-15   0
25-Aug-15   0
26-Aug-15   0
27-Aug-15   0
28-Aug-15   11
29-Aug-15   0
30-Aug-15   0
31-Aug-15   0
01-Sep-15   0
02-Sep-15   0
03-Sep-15   0
04-Sep-15   0
```

Result

```
Date    Count
14-Aug-15   0
15-Aug-15   20
16-Aug-15   20
17-Aug-15   20
18-Aug-15   20
19-Aug-15   20
20-Aug-15   14
21-Aug-15   14
22-Aug-15   14
23-Aug-15   10
24-Aug-15   10
25-Aug-15   10
26-Aug-15   10
27-Aug-15   10
28-Aug-15   11
29-Aug-15   11
30-Aug-15   11
31-Aug-15   11
01-Sep-15   11
02-Sep-15   11
03-Sep-15   11
04-Sep-15   11
```

Comment: Too much data, too little effort.  Please pare down your sample data to 10-15 rows.

Comment: Can consider the data below, also add a coulmn with id values like A,B,C.. repetative.

Comment: You need to update your answer properly so the expected result is clearly stated! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple subquery can get you your result set as desired (with the last current or previous non-zero value).

```
select [Date], 
       isnull((select top 1 [Previous].[Count] 
               from [Table] as [Previous]
               where [Previous].[Count] <> 0 and 
                     [Previous].[Date] <= [Table].[Date] and
                     [Previous].[Id] = [Table].[Id]
               order by [Previous].[Date] desc),
              0) as [Count]
from [Table]
```

To update values is very similar :

```
update [Table] set [Count]= isnull((select top 1 [Previous].[Count] 
                                    from [Table] as [Previous]
                                    where [Previous].[Count] <> 0 and 
                                          [Previous].[Date] <= [Table].[Date] and
                                          [Previous].[Id] = [Table].[Id]
                                    order by [Previous].[Date] desc),
                                   0) as [Count]
```

Comment: works but i have a id column with value like A,B,C. so the query should match the id and update the value.

Comment: n d c
A 14-08-2015 0
B 15-08-2015 20
B 16-08-2015 0
A 17-08-2015 0
C 18-08-2015 0
A 19-08-2015 10
D 20-08-2015 14
A 21-08-2015 0

Comment: Can you update your question adding those id values on the sample set and the result set ?. I don't get what you do with them.

Comment: You got me wrong, i have added the column N. while selecting/updating the value id should be same. for example count for 16 August should become 20, as B has a value of 20 before. But value of 17th August should be zero as last value of A was 0

Comment: Result n d c Result
A 14-08-2015 0 0
B 15-08-2015 20 20
B 16-08-2015 0 20
A 17-08-2015 0 0
C 18-08-2015 0 0
A 19-08-2015 10 10
D 20-08-2015 14 14
A 21-08-2015 0 10

Comment: @Ansh update your question otherwise you are asking for more downvotes

Comment: Ok, I have update the answer to match that Id column. As Radim said, you should add those columns on the question to make it clear. Regards.

Comment: Apologies for this time, i will make sure i do it. In a rush so cant change it now. Thanks Marc & Radim.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a variable to achieve it

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
  n VARCHAR(10),
  d DATE,
  c INT
);


INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('A', '14-Aug-15', 0);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('B', '15-Aug-15', 20);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('C', '16-Aug-15', 0);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('A', '17-Aug-15', 0);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('B', '18-Aug-15', 0);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('C', '19-Aug-15', 0);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('D', '20-Aug-15', 14);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('A', '21-Aug-15', 0);

-- for each n value perform the following update
DECLARE @last INT=0;
UPDATE tab 
SET @last=c=CASE WHEN c=0 THEN @last ELSE c END
WHERE n = 'B';
```

Comment: works but i have a id column with value like A,B,C. so the query should match the id and update the value.

Comment: @ansh you need to update your answer properly so the expected result is clearly stated!

Answer (score 0):

I think below code should work for you -

```
Create table #Source  (
id  char(1) ,
date smalldatetime,
value tinyint)
go

insert into  #Source 
 select 'A' ,'14-Aug-15' ,  0
union all  select 'B' , '15-Aug-15' ,  20
union all  select 'B'  , '16-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B'  , '17-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B'  , '18-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'A' , '19-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'A' , '20-Aug-15'  , 14
union all  select 'A' , '21-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B' , '22-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B', '23-Aug-15'  , 10
union all  select 'B' , '24-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B' , '25-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B' , '26-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'C' , '27-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'C' , '28-Aug-15'  , 11
union all  select 'C' , '29-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'C' , '30-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'C' , '31-Aug-15'  , 0
union all  select 'C' , '01-Sep-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B' , '02-Sep-15'  , 0
union all  select 'B' , '03-Sep-15'  , 0
union all  select 'A' , '04-Sep-15'  , 0



select t1.* , t2.value  New_value  ,  RANK() over ( partition by t1.date  
order by  t2.date desc    )  as RANK
into #dest
from #Source t1
left join #Source t2 on t1.id = t2.id and  t1.date >= t2.date  
and  t1.value=0 and t2.value <>0
order by 2

update s
set s.Value =  d.New_value  
from  #Source s join #dest d
on s.id = d.id 
and s.date = d.date 
and d.RANK = 1 and  d.New_value   is not null
```